# How to eliminate points by difference (vector geo processing tool)?

Tags: qgis

I have a point that falls outside the bounds of my area of study. What I did was select it and resorted to vector commands - GIS - difference. Unfortunately I can not get the desired result. My shapefile has 500 points and I have to eliminate one and I can not get 499 . I have some doubts what to put in the vector layer of input and difference layer.

How do a remove this one point?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! It is unclear what you are asking - do you want to edit and delete a single point? Please click 'edit' and clarify your question.

Comment: I want to eliminate points by comand vector - geo processing tool - difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your area study is a vector layer and points are on the second vector layer you can use "Spatial Query" function from  vector menu.

```
    1. Select source layer ("points") and pick from a combobox query method ex. "intersects"
    2. Select reference future (your "area study") and get result ex. "new selection"
    3. At the result you will get poinst in "area study"
    4. Save as new layer.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to delete a point? If so, I'm not sure why you would want to use the Difference tool. Artec has described above how to identify the points which fall inside the study area (note that Spatial Query is a plugin, which you may need to add). Rather than saving the selection as a new layer, alternatively you could select the inverse (points outside the study area) and delete them.

If what you're asking is as simple as "How do I delete one point of known location from a shapefile?", then turn on editing, select the point and delete. Save your edits and you're done.